# python string parsing given sql query tell if it's read or write

Tags: python, sql, string, parsing

I'm given a sql query and I have to decide if it's a write statement or read statement.

I'm not sure how to go about it and I can't find anything online that already has this capability.

I'm assuming the only way to do it is to inspect the string for words like `select` vs `update alter delete insert drop etc...`

But I'll have to strip out all string literals first.

```
def is_write_query(query):
    # returns true or false 
    # strip string literals 
    # if contains key words: 
    #   UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT, CREATE, ALTER, DROP
    # return true, else false
```

Does anyone know a better way to do this? do you know about a package that has this capability?

if this is the best way to do it, what's the easiest way to handle the string parsing? Specifically stripping out the string literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a better way than what you suggest - you need to look at the operation that is happening. The operation will always be the first word in the query so you can do:

```
def is_write_query(query): 
    query = query.lower().strip() # to remove trailing and leading whitespace, convert to lowercase 
    if query.startswith(("update","insert","create","alter","delete","drop")): 
        return True 
    else:
        return False
```

You might need to include more keywords than I am including here, but this would be the general idea. 
`.startswith()` can take a tuple (not list) of string to try which is what is happening here.

Comment: actually, these statements can be pretty complex, so the first word might not be the operation. For instance, it could start with a `with` if it's creating a CTE table first. But thanks, this is a good start.

Comment: Counter example, you can begin with an alias or a sub request, and the operation comes later: `WITH tmp as (SELECT col1 FROM tb1) DELETE FROM tmp WHERE col1 = tmp.col1`